# Textviews of custom adapter is not occupying the specified space in the screen

Tags: android

I have got two xml files called `compliance_details.xml` and `compliance_details_row.xml`

Following is my compliance_details.xml code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/taskNameLabel"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="TaskName"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dueDateLabel"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="Due Date"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ageingLabel"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="Ageiging"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>


and following is my compliance_details_row.xml code

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/taskNameValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="TaskName"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dueDateValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Due Date"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ageingValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Ageiging"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

In my adapter, Im inflating the compliance_details_row.xml with compliance_row.xml.

But when Im doing so, the elements of compliance_details_row is bit distorted.[image]

As you could see from the above picture, the compliance names should be coming under the title `TaskName` but the compliance names are bit distorted and also due date values are only partly visible . How can I be able to sort this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need a TableLayout to achieve this. Just use a LinearLayout with weightSum. To get the desired proportions - change the weight values for each TextView.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3">

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/taskNameValue"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="TaskName"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dueDateValue"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Due Date"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ageingValue"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Ageiging"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the taskname, duedate and agin... from your parent view (`compliance_details_row.xml` ) and add it as the first element in your custom adapter. the `compliance_row.xml` only makes sure that the rows inside this layout are in `Table` format, it has no control over the parent layout's views. so, either change both `compliance_details_row.xml` and `compliance_row.xml` into  `LinearLayout` with `weight` or remove the three elements from the`compliance_details_row.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use LinearLayout with `android:layout_weight` property for both xml :

**compliance_details.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/taskNameLabel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:text="TaskName"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dueDateLabel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:text="Due Date"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ageingLabel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:text="Ageiging"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" />
```

**compliance_details_row.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/taskNameValue"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="TaskName"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dueDateValue"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Due Date"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ageingValue"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Ageiging"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```